# Run loop to build co-occurrence matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have the below dataframe and hoping to:

(1) build a 4x4 co-occurrence matrix.

(2) use a loop to run this, as I am using a much larger dataset with more variables.

```
a <- rep(c("a", "a", "b", "c"), 4)
b <- rep(c("b", "c", "d", "d"), 4)
df <- data.frame(a,b)

out <- matrix(0, 
              nrow = 4, # how do I call just the levels?
              ncol = 4)
out
```

The below code did not work, but may assist in someone helping me figure this out.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  ind <- which(lvls == df[i, "a"]) 
  out[i, ind] <- 1 
}
out

# loop over variables in b
for (j in 1:nrow(df)) {
  ind <- which(lvls == df[j, "b"]) 
  out[j, ind] <- 1 
}
out
```

Here is the output I am hoping for...

```
       [a]  [b]  [c]  [d]
[a]     0    4    4    0
[b]     4    0    0    4
[c]     4    0    0    4
[d]     0    4    4    0
```

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please also post the desired result from your example

Comment: @bpace In the example provided, there is no `a` and `d` rows and same for `b` and `c`.  I couldn't understand how you got `4`.  Check the output of `table(as.character(interaction(df, sep="")))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
 lvls <- sort(as.character(unique(unlist(df))))
 df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) factor(x, levels=lvls) )
 m1 <- table(df)
 m1[lower.tri(m1)] <- m1[upper.tri(m1)]
 class(m1) <- "matrix"
 dimnames(m1) <- unname(dimnames(m1)) #as suggested by @Richard Scriven
 m1
 #    a b c d
 #  a 0 4 4 0
 #  b 4 0 0 4
 #  c 4 0 0 4
 #  d 0 4 4 0
```

#### Update

Suppose, if your data is changed (contributed by @user20650)

```
df[1, ] <- c("b", "a")
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) factor(x, levels=lvls) )
m1 <- table(df)
m2 <- m1 + t(m1)
m2 #you can convert to class `matrix` and change the dimnames as above
#    b
#a b a c d
#b 0 4 0 4
#a 4 0 4 0
#c 0 4 0 4
#d 4 0 4 0
```

#### Update2

If, you don't want a `symmetric` matrix and would like to have the actual `counts`

```
 df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) factor(x, levels=lvls) )
 m1 <- table(df)
 indx <- !m1 & lower.tri(m1)
 m1[indx] <- m1[t(indx)]
 class(m1) <- "matrix"
 dimnames(m1) <- unname(dimnames(m1))
 m1
 #  b a c d
 #b 0 1 0 4
 #a 3 0 4 0
 #c 0 4 0 4
 #d 4 0 4 0

 table(as.character(interaction(df,sep="")))

 #ab ac ba bd cd 
 #3  4  1  4  4
```

#### Update3

Regarding multiple variables, I am not sure about the expected result, perhaps this helps:

```
indx <- combn(colnames(df1),2)
res <- Reduce(`+`,lapply(split(indx, col(indx)), function(x) table(df1[x])))
dimnames(res) <- unname(dimnames(res))
res
#   a  b  c  d  e  f  g
#a  4  9  5  4  2  6  5
#b  8  6 13  6  5  9  3
#c  6  8  7  5  2  7  2
#d  4  3  5  6  2  2  6
#e  8  6  8 11  3  5  5
#f  4  4  3  5  2  1  4
#g  1  4  2  5  3  2  4
```

#### data

```
a <- rep(c("a", "a", "b", "c"), 4)
b <- rep(c("b", "c", "d", "d"), 4)
df <- data.frame(a,b, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Data with multiple columns

```
 set.seed(24)
 df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(letters[1:7], 6*16, replace=TRUE), ncol=6))
 lvls1 <- sort(as.character(unique(unlist(df1))))
 df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) factor(x, levels=lvls1))
```